# What are these sensors on the Night Stalkers' Chinook MH-47G?

Tags: military, helicopter, sensors, ch-47

What are these sensors (or lights) on this heavy assault Chinook MH-47G of the US [160th Special Operations Aviation Regiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/160th_Special_Operations_Aviation_Regiment_(Airborne)), "*Night Stalkers*"?

[image]
<sup>[Source](http://www.airliners.net/photo/USA-Army/Boeing-MH-47G-Chinook-414/2281241), picture by [Russell Hill](http://www.airliners.net/user/sabian404/profile/photos)</sup>

This regiment was the subject of Ridley Scott's *[Black Hawk Down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Hawk_Down_(film))*.

Comment: Well... they _featured_ in it but that movie is really about the Rangers.

Comment: @Gaius: You're right, the Black Hawks from the 160th SOAR were used to support the [Ranger task force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Mogadishu_(1993)#Task_Force_Ranger).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those sensors are part of the AN/AVR-2A Laser Warning System. Here is a closeup of the system components.

[image: AN/AVR-2A]

*The AN/AVR-2A is a passive laser warning system which receives, processes and displays threat information resulting from aircraft illumination by laser designators, range finders and beam riding missiles. ... The AN/AVR-2A LDS consists of one interface unit comparator and four identical sensor units.*; image from [thaimilitaryandasianregion.wordpress.com](https://thaimilitaryandasianregion.wordpress.com/2015/11/12/)

These sensors are installed on the MH-47G Chinook, as given in [americanspecialops.com](http://www.americanspecialops.com/night-stalkers/helicopters/mh-47.php)

> **Defensive systems**
>
> Common Missile Warning System (CMWS)
>
> Suite Of Integrated Radio Frequency Countermeasures (SIRFC)
>
> AN/AVR-2b Laser Warning System
>
> XM216 Dark Flares (invisible to naked eye)